# Uploading file via visualforce page error "Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded"

Tags: apex, visualforce, upload, document

I am trying to implement a page that I will upload files through it, but I keep having this error

> Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size
>   for this page was 158.328KB

Here is my visualforce form

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
         <apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}" filename="{!document.name}" id="file"/> 
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Description" for="description"/>
        <apex:inputTextarea value="{!document.description}" id="description"/>
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>
 <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Upload"/>
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

and here is my APEX code

```
public List<Document> documents{set;get;}
public Document document 
{
  get 
  {
    if (document == null)
      document = new Document();
      return document;
  }
  set;
}
document.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    document.FolderId = account.ID;
    try {
       insert document;
    } catch (DMLException e) {
       ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error'));
    } finally {
       document.body = null;
       document = new Document();
       documents = [SELECT Query];
    }
```

What is the problem here ?

---

Update: The query was like this

```
documents = [SELECT Description, body, Id, Name, Url FROM Document WHERE
AuthorId =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

but it works after I removed `body`

```
documents = [SELECT Description, Id, Name, Url FROM Document WHERE
AuthorId =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

Comment: Can you paste your update code.

Comment: @Sathya I've just updated it.

Comment: I have to declare a document variable as a transient...??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making your Document object transient. Its not evident from your code.
And what is that 'documents' in the end, where you try to query something?

Comment: Yes actually, but the error has changed to this "Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size for this page was 158.328KB"

Comment: Dont change the question after someone answers. That makes the answer completely out of context. Open a new question if required, after closing the previous one. Anyway, I have updated my answer.

Comment: documents is a List<document>

Comment: I think that might be the problem. Dont query the document body in that query (the query in the question is not complete).

Comment: you are right MR :D, thx.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70483/file-attachment-upload-maximum-file-size-limit-exceeded-135mb

Answer (score 2):

Following information can be provided according to the question:-

- Make document variable transient and also make `document = null;`
- Also do not query `body` field in SOQL if you are querying that. e.eg; `[SELECT id, body FROM Document]`. This may hit controller heap size and page viewstate (if referenced on Visualforce page)

Comment: @Ashwani : Have look into this problem plz - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70483/file-attachment-upload-maximum-file-size-limit-exceeded-135mb

Comment: @Nilesh you CSN use tansient keyword to prevent viewstate.

Comment: @Ashwani : CSN ? 
And Its giving me some sort of error msg when I declare variable as Transient. It works with some variable but still go for Viewstate error.